# how this for loop is used in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please let me know how this for loop is working.

```
 points = {0,1,2,3,4,8,1}
 x = float(sum([len(points) for i in points]))
 print(x)
```

This code snippet is giving me output as:-

```
36.0
```

Comment: It is printing `len(points) ^ 2`because the sum is the length of points for each element in points (i.e., the length again). Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi Deepak, what are you trying to achieve here? As others have pointed out, you are taking `len(points)` eg. `len({0,1,2,3,4,8})` which returns 6, and therefore the sum is actually `sum([6,6,6,6,6,6])` which returns 36. But what is it you are actually trying to do? if you did `len(i)` you would just get 6, which i doubt is the intention.

Comment: You have to look more into what `for i in points` do and also what is the value for `len(points)`

Comment: `float` converts its input into float `type` number, `sum` does exactly what is says, it outputs a sum of the input, depending on what is inside, in this case it is a `list`, so it sums `points` length n-times, where `n` is the number of elements in `points` set, thus we get 6+6+6+6+6+6 = 36 converted to `float` = 36.0

Comment: Hi Vincent, actually I am not getting if numbers are not in increasing order then it gives the square of the length of the longest increasing sequence.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Values in the `set` doesn't matter as you are just counting them, not doing anything to the values themeselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions are not that hard if you take a look at a very simple example:

```
[T(x) for x in X]
```

The first term is declaring what should be done with all the individual items in the collection we are iterating over. This might be type conversion or just extracting a specific value from a dict.

The symbol after the `for` just defines the name for our iteration variable and the last term is the collection(list, set, dict etc.) which we iterate through.

A more verbose implementation of the same thing could be:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    result.append(T(X[i]))
```

After this the content of result is the same as the list returned by the list comprehension.

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the case ... x)